# What is the most efficient way to populate a table

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I am looking for the fastest way to get data in to an HTML table.. I am using MVC3 and have a table that is being updated every few seconds on several clients machines.

What I need to know is what is the quickest method of getting latest server data on that table.

Currently, we just do ajax calls and return a partial view each time. that partial view just contains the table. Is there any advantage to returning the data as JSON and clearing the table down and appending the JSON directly to the table?

I looked in to signalr but none of our equipment is likely to be websocket compatible in the near future so couldnt really see the advantages of diving in with that.

Failing that - can anyone offer any alternative views on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [**SignalR**](http://signalr.net/) to push to client only the required changes.

> ASP.NET SignalR is a new library for ASP.NET developers that makes it
>   incredibly simple to add real-time web functionality to your
>   applications. What is "real-time web" functionality? It's the ability
>   to have your server-side code push content to the connected clients as
>   it happens, in real-time.
>
> You may have heard of WebSockets, a new HTML5 API that enables
>   bi-directional communication between the browser and server. SignalR
>   will use WebSockets under the covers when it's available, and
>   gracefully fallback to other techniques and technologies when it
>   isn't, while your application code stays the same.
>
> SignalR also provides a very simple, high-level API for doing server
>   to client RPC (call JavaScript functions in your clients' browsers
>   from server-side .NET code) in your ASP.NET application, as well as
>   adding useful hooks for connection management, e.g. connect/disconnect
>   events, grouping connections, authorization.

Comment: Can I get away with this with all the server 2003 and windows xp machines that I have at my disposal? Would it cut down on the constant polling that is going on at the moment?

Comment: SignalR uses various techniques to transfer data which depend on what the browser supports. It should work for you - SignalR has little overheard on the server.

Comment: You will never get websockets with that server setup. SignalR will fallback to SSE, forever frame and longpolling.

Answer (score 1):

You say that you equipment does not support websockets. Are you talking about server side or client side?

We are using 2003 & 2008 server and threw SignalR out for xsockets.net. Xsockets support websockets on all platforms. Framework runs on .NET 4.0 and is Mono compatible.

If you do not have 2012 server (or win8) and .NET 4.5 + IIS8 you will not get websockets with SignalR :( But it can still be a good option if your application does not require speed.

In our case we needed speed even on 2003, 2008 server, hence the choice of Xsockets.

There is a nice comparison table here: http://xsockets.net/xsockets-vs-signalr